# How can i add a sample grabber filter to the graph i have so i can save images/video from the streaming preview using directshow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directshow, graphedit

The device in the usb is legato game capture.
The streaming preview in the pictureBox1 show the video from the device but it's not pixels that I can save from the pictureBox1 as images.

" There is no way to grab a shot of a window that is not actually being displayed. If the window is not completely visible, then those pixels simply do not exist. "

Another problem is that I can't find the legato game capture device in graphedit. I also tried graphedit plus. But the legato device not exist there in the list.

This is how i'm creating the preview and streaming it in pictureBox1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectShowLib;
using DirectShowLib.BDA;
using DirectShowLib.DES;
using DirectShowLib.DMO;
using DirectShowLib.Dvd;
using DirectShowLib.MultimediaStreaming;
using DirectShowLib.SBE;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace Youtube_Manager
{

    public partial class Elgato_Video_Capture : Form
    {


        IFileSinkFilter sink;

        IFilterGraph2 graph;
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph;
        System.Drawing.Size videoSize;

        string error = "";
        List<Object> devices = new List<Object>();
        IMediaControl mediaControl;

        public Elgato_Video_Capture()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                for (int xx = 1; xx <= 8; xx++)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(xx);
                }
            }

            InitDevice();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        IBaseFilter smartTeeFilter;
        IPin outPin;
        IPin inPin;
        private void InitDevice()
        {
            try
            {
                //Set the video size to use for capture and recording
                videoSize = new Size(827, 505);//1280, 720);

                //Initialize filter graph and capture graph
                graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
                captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
                captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(graph);
                //Create filter for Elgato
                Guid elgatoGuid = new Guid("39F50F4C-99E1-464A-B6F9-D605B4FB5918");
                Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(elgatoGuid);
                IBaseFilter  elgatoFilter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
                graph.AddFilter(elgatoFilter, "Elgato Video Capture Filter");

                //Create smart tee filter, add to graph, connect Elgato's video out to smart tee in
                smartTeeFilter = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();

                graph.AddFilter(smartTeeFilter, "Smart Tee");
                outPin = GetPin(elgatoFilter, "Video");
                inPin = GetPin(smartTeeFilter, "Input");
                SetAndGetAllAvailableResolution(outPin);
                graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);


                //Create video renderer filter, add it to graph, connect smartTee Preview pin to video renderer's input pin
                IBaseFilter videoRendererFilter = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRenderer();

                graph.AddFilter(videoRendererFilter, "Video Renderer");
                outPin = GetPin(smartTeeFilter, "Preview");

                inPin = GetPin(videoRendererFilter, "Input");
                graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

               // int hr = graph.Connect(outPin, inPin); ;
               // DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

                captureGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, @"e:\screenshots\test1.mp4", out smartTeeFilter, out sink);

                //Render stream from video renderer
                captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.VideoPort, MediaType.Video, videoRendererFilter, null, null);
                //Set the video preview to be the videoFeed panel
                IVideoWindow vw = (IVideoWindow)graph;
                vw.put_Owner(pictureBox1.Handle);
                vw.put_MessageDrain(this.Handle);
                vw.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings | WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
                vw.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, 827, 505);

                //Start the preview
                mediaControl = graph as IMediaControl;
                mediaControl.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                error = err.ToString();
            }
        }

         IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter filter, string pinname)
        {
            IEnumPins epins;
            int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't enumerate pins");
            IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
            IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
            while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
            {
                PinInfo pinfo;
                pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
                bool found = (pinfo.name == pinname);
                DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
                if (found)
                    return pins[0];
            }
            checkHR(-1, "Pin not found");
            return null;
        }

        public  void checkHR(int hr, string msg)
        {
            if (hr < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }



        }

        public void SetAndGetAllAvailableResolution(IPin VideoOutPin)
        {
            int hr = 0;
            IAMStreamConfig streamConfig = (IAMStreamConfig)VideoOutPin;
            AMMediaType searchmedia;
            AMMediaType CorectvidFormat = new AMMediaType();
            IntPtr ptr;
            int piCount, piSize;
            hr = streamConfig.GetNumberOfCapabilities(out piCount, out piSize);
            ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(piSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < piCount; i++)
            {
                hr = streamConfig.GetStreamCaps(i, out searchmedia, ptr);
                VideoInfoHeader v = new VideoInfoHeader();

                Marshal.PtrToStructure(searchmedia.formatPtr, v);
                if (i == 2)// 4
                {
                    CorectvidFormat = searchmedia;
                }
            }
            hr = streamConfig.SetFormat(CorectvidFormat);

            IntPtr pmt = IntPtr.Zero;
            AMMediaType mediaType = new AMMediaType();
            IAMStreamConfig streamConfig1 = (IAMStreamConfig)VideoOutPin;
            hr = streamConfig1.GetFormat(out mediaType);
            BitmapInfoHeader bmpih = new BitmapInfoHeader();
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.formatPtr, bmpih);
        }
  }
}
```

Now i tried to add this methods to use with the sample grabber:

```
private void AddSampleGrabber(int hr, Guid elgatoguid, IFilterGraph2 pGraph)
        {
            //add SampleGrabber
            IBaseFilter pSampleGrabber = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(elgatoguid));
            hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSampleGrabber, "SampleGrabber");
            checkHR(hr, "Can't add SampleGrabber to graph");
            //set callback
            hr = ((ISampleGrabber)pSampleGrabber).SetCallback(new SampleGrabberCallback(), 0);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't set callback.");

            AMMediaType pmt = new AMMediaType();
            pmt.majorType = MediaType.Video;
            pmt.subType = MediaSubType.YUY2;
            pmt.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
            pmt.fixedSizeSamples = true;
            pmt.formatSize = 88;
            pmt.sampleSize = 614400;
            pmt.temporalCompression = false;
            VideoInfoHeader format = new VideoInfoHeader();
            format.SrcRect = new DsRect();
            format.TargetRect = new DsRect();
            format.BmiHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader();
            format.BmiHeader.Size = 40;
            format.BmiHeader.Width = 640;
            format.BmiHeader.Height = 480;
            format.BmiHeader.Planes = 1;
            format.BmiHeader.BitCount = 16;
            format.BmiHeader.Compression = 844715353;
            format.BmiHeader.ImageSize = 614400;
            pmt.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(format));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(format, pmt.formatPtr, false);
            hr = ((IAMStreamConfig)GetPin(smartTeeFilter, "Capture")).SetFormat(pmt);
            DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(pmt);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't set format");

            //connect USB2.0 Camera and SampleGrabber
            hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(smartTeeFilter, "Capture"), GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Input"), null);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't connect USB2.0 Camera and SampleGrabber");

            //render the video
            hr = captureGraph.RenderStream(null, null, pSampleGrabber, null, null);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't render video from grabber");

        }

        class SampleGrabberCallback : ISampleGrabberCB
        {
            public SampleGrabberCallback()
            {
            }

            public int BufferCB(double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int BufferLen)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            public int SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample pSample)
            {
                if (pSample == null) return -1;
                int len = pSample.GetActualDataLength();
                IntPtr pbuf;
                if (pSample.GetPointer(out pbuf) == 0 && len > 0)
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[len];
                    Marshal.Copy(pbuf, buf, 0, len);
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
                        buf[i] = (byte)(255 - buf[i]);
                    Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, pbuf, len);
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

But i'm getting exception on the line:

```
hr = ((ISampleGrabber)pSampleGrabber).SetCallback(new SampleGrabberCallback(), 0);
```

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'DirectShowLib.ISampleGrabber'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6B652FFF-11FE-4FCE-92AD-0266B5D7C78F}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

I guess i'm not using it right at all.
And also I don't know how to use it later on to grab(save to hard disk) image/video of the streaming.

Answer (score 0):

The code around `pSampleGrabber` makes no sense. It expects a COM pointer to [Sample Grabber Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377544) instance. No other filters are expected to implement `ISampleGrabber`. You however are trying to cast video capture filter to what it is not supposed to be (`E_NOINTERFACE` tells you exactly this!):

```
IBaseFilter pSampleGrabber = 
    (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(elgatoguid));
```

You need to add video capture filter, then create Sample Grabber instance, and then connect the two. Then render grabber's output. Then associate your callback with grabber instance.

Comment: I can't find yet how to make the first step add a video capture filter. Tried to google but could not find. Is that so hard to do ?

Comment: Capture filter is created and added to the graph in your first posted code snippet (around `elgatoFilter`).